# how can a variable contain array content if used out of context

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var name = new Array('freddy', 'mac', 'fanny', 'may');
var content = 'hi '.+name[i]+.'!';

$('div.class').each(function (i) {
this.html(content);
});
```

This javascript should output
hi freddy!
hi mac!
hi fanny!
hi may!

but there is an error for the var because it refrences an array that has not been set up yet.

Comment: Did you notice you're missing a `'` on the second line there?

Comment: What context? You're using `.+` which is not an operator and you need `$(this)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a value to the `content` variable, and a value is evaluated when you assign the value, not when you use the variable. I.e. a plain value can not contain a reference to another value.

You can make it a function that evaluates the value when it's called:

```
var name = new Array('freddy', 'mac', 'fanny', 'may');
var content = function(i) { return 'hi ' + name[i] + '!'};

$('div.class').each(function (i) {
  $(this).html(content(i));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't sort your quotes right, and since `i` doesn't exist at the time content is assigned it won't work anyway. You should try this:

```
var content = 'hi, {0}!';

$('div.class').each(function(i) {
    this.html(content.replace("{0}", name[i]));
});
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo ill fix that